# Hide nested html elements except the first two (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<ol class="feeds">
  <li class="feed"></li>
  <strong>
    <li class="feed"></li>
    <strong>
      <li class="feed"></li>
      <strong>
        <!-- and so on -->
      </strong>
    </strong>
  </strong>
</ol>
```

How can I hide all the `.feed` elements except the first and the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$(".feed:gt(1)").hide(); //since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing so we have to use '1' in index.
```

Read more about `:gt()` [here.](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Comment: ol has feeds li has feed

Comment: @Kartikeya Oh, I forgot to mention the elements are dynamically generated with JS. Do I need to add `.on` somewhere?

Comment: @alexchenco No, you don't need.

Comment: @alexchenco...no you don't need .on() where your are generating html dynamically just write this code there.

Comment: It's a twitter feed. So I don't have access to that part.

Comment: where you are generating html from twitter feed in your page ... then after appending html in DOM write this code ... if you use `.on()` then you must have a event like `click` or something on that event you can hide element,so try hiding element while you are appending your dom with twitter feed...@alexchenco

Answer (score 2):

You can also use below:

```
 $('.feed:not(:nth-child(1)),.feed:not(:nth-child(2))').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$(".feed").each(function(i) {
    if (i == 1 || i == 2) return;
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".feed:gt(1)").hide()` like this:

```js
$(".feed:gt(1)").hide()
```

```html
<ol class="feeds">
  <li class="feed">f</li>
  <strong>
    <li class="feed">s</li>
    <strong>
      <li class="feed">t</li>
      <strong>
        <!-- and so on -->
      </strong>
    </strong>
  </strong>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use CSS compatible selector `$('.feed:nth-child(n+3)').hide()`, in which n >= 0, and the counter starts from 1.

Or maybe you could just get rid of JS, use CSS only `.feed:nth-child(n+3) { display: none; }`